# Laurent expansion of $\frac{16}{z^2(z-3)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

> What is Laurent series of $\frac{16}{z^2(z-3)}$ at $z=3$ in the inner annulus?

$\frac{16}{z^2(z-3)}=\frac{-16}{3z^2}-\frac{16}{9z}+\frac{16}{9(z-3)} = \frac{16}{9}(z-3)^{-1}+\frac{16}{27}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{(z-3)}{3}}-\frac{16}{3z^2}$

What can I do to turn $\frac{16}{3z^2}$ to a geometric series?

Comment: Hint: $\frac{d}{dz}  \frac{1}{z} = -\frac{1}{z^2}$. Can you write a series for $\frac{1}{z}$?

Comment: Could you define inner annulus?

Answer (score 1):

$${1 \over z^2} = \left( {1 \over 3 + (z - 3)} \right)^2.$$
Now,
$$
{1 \over 3 + (z - 3)}  = {1 \over 3} \left({1 \over 1 + \left({1\over 3}\right)(z-3)}\right) 
= {1 \over 3} \left({1 \over 1 - \left(-{1\over 3}\right)(z-3)}\right) = 
{1 \over 3} \sum_{k \geq 0} \left[ \left(-{1\over 3}\right)(z-3) \right]^{k}.
$$
Finally, you will need to square the geometric series, and this can be done by using [the Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product).

I heartily recommend [Cartan's textbook](https://www.pdfdrive.com/elementary-theory-of-analytic-functions-of-one-or-several-complex-variables-e196375670.html) for this material.